# Syntax error when calling a stored procedure with nested strings in the parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to restore database in SQL Server 2008 R2 using a bak file and stored procedure of Lite speed. Below is my Code:

```
USE Master
Go 
exec master.dbo.XP_RESTORE_DATABASE
@database="abc"
,@filename='M:\BACKUPS\xyz.bak'
,@WITH= 'REPLACE'
,@WITH= 'MOVE' "abc_DATA" TO "H:\SQLDATA\ABC.mdf"'
,@WITH= 'MOVE' "abc_LOG" TO "H:\SQLDATA\ABC.ldf"'
GO
```

After executing the above query I got below error:

Incorrect Syntax near 'abc_DATA'.

I don't know why I am getting this error as I always used this query to restore database.

Comment: That doesn't look right - you have imbalanced `'` characters there. A quick hunt suggests that the `'` immediately after `MOVE` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Why aren't you using the RESTORE command?

Comment: `xp_restore_database` is *not* a SQL Server procedure. It's a part of the Litespeed product

Comment: Litespeed's docs for [xp_restore_database](https://support.quest.com/technical-documents/litespeed-for-sql-server/7.5/netvault-litespeed-for-sql-server-user-guide/21#TOPIC-113106). In any case, your string parameter terminates righ after `'MOVE'`. That second `'` means only `MOVE` is part of the string. Remove it in both cases, ie write ,`@WITH= 'MOVE "abc_DATA" TO "H:\SQLDATA\ABC.mdf"'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the [tag:litespeed] tag doesn't appear to be anything to do with a database product.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is a LiteSpeed command.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yes, but the [tag:litespeed] tag describes itself as being related to the Litespeed Web Server.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see this now. There's no tag even for Quest, much less the litespeed product

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [abc]
FROM DISK = [DiskLocation]
WITH MOVE 'abc_data' TO ' H:\SQLDATA\ABC.mdf'
,MOVE 'abc_log' TO 'H:\SQLDATA\ABC.ldf'
```

Comment: It appears that they're using a separate product for managing their backups. Possibly with compression. It's unlikely that the native `RESTORE` command can comprehend the contents of the backup file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Damien, i wasn't initially aware.

Answer (score 0):

`XP_RESTORE_DATABASE` isn't a SQL Server procedure. It's part of Quest's LiteSpeed product . The docs for `xp_restore_database` are [here](https://support.quest.com/technical-documents/litespeed-for-sql-server/7.5/netvault-litespeed-for-sql-server-user-guide/21#TOPIC-113106)

Second, the message explains what's wrong. The call isn't correct. The string value passed to the `@WITH` parameter is terminated right after `MOVE` and followed by an *object identifier* `"abc_DATA"`.

The call should be :

```
exec master.dbo.XP_RESTORE_DATABASE @database="abc", @filename='M:\BACKUPS\xyz.bak'
        ,@WITH= 'REPLACE'
        ,@WITH= 'MOVE "abc_DATA" TO "H:\SQLDATA\ABC.mdf"'
        ,@WITH= 'MOVE "abc_LOG" TO "H:\SQLDATA\ABC.ldf"'
```

You'll notice that syntax coloring paints the entire string red now.